# Symfony: Collection and subform required option & validator not working

Tags: symfony, validation, required, subform

I have a Form which embeds a collectionType.
The Collection type uses two subforms.

When I set required option to fields belonging to CollectionType form or Subforms, it does not work: neither red * nor form validation errors...

I have a Form which embeds a collectionType.
The Collection type uses two subforms.

When I set required option to fields belonging to CollectionType form or Subforms, it does not work: neither red * nor form validation errors...

What did I miss ?

```
     Classe:
                class: App\Entity\Classe
                label: 'Classes'
                form:
                   fields: 
                      - { property: 'classe', label: 'Classe Name'}
                      - { property: 'maxextcuth', label: 'Max ext. Cu', type: 'entity'}
                      - { property: 'maxintcuth', label: 'Max int. Cu', type: 'entity'} 
                      - { property: 'enabled', label: 'Enabled'}  
                      - { type: 'section', label: 'Price rules', icon: 'euro' }
                      - property: 'classePrices'
                        label: false
                        type: 'collection'
                        type_options:
                           entry_type: App\Form\Type\ClassePriceType
                           allow_delete: true
                           allow_add: true
                           by_reference: false
                           prototype: true
                           block_prefix: 'price_collection'



        class ClassePriceType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
            ->add('priceform', PriceformType::class, [
                'data_class' => ClassePrice::class,
                'block_prefix' => 'mainprice_block'

            ]);
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => ClassePrice::class,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'fullwidth'
                )
            ]);
        }
    }

class PriceformType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('pricecover', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Price type',
            'placeholder' => 'Select a price option',
            'choices' => [ 'Global' => '1' ,'Step' => '2'],
            'required' => true
        ])
        ->add('rangesubform', RangesubformType::class, [
            'data_class' => ClassePrice::class,
            'block_prefix' => 'range_block'

        ])
        ->add('pricesubform', PricesubformType::class, [
            'data_class' => ClassePrice::class,
            'block_prefix' => 'price_block'
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'inherit_data' => true
        ]);
    }
}

class RangesubformType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('rangetype', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Ptur::class,
            'label' => 'Step type',
            'choice_translation_domain'=> true,
            'required' => true
        ])
        ->add('rangeformat', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Format::class,
                'label' => 'Format',
                'required' => true
        ])
        ->add('rangemin', IntegerType::class, [
            'label' => 'Range min',
            'required' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'inherit_data' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-horizontal'
            )
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html